# How to change axis with fill_between

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

With matplotlib, how can you fill between function and y axis instead of x?

The normal way for filling between function and x axis is:

```
ax.fill_between(x, y, interpolate=True, color='red')
```

I was going to plot as normal and then rotate by 90 but it also seems tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you are looking for [`fill_betweenx`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx.html):

```
ax.fill_betweenx(x, y, color='red')
```

Note that this method does not accept an `interpolte` parameter, though. 
There are more examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_betweenx_demo.html).

Comment: Thanks! I searched online for something like that but must not have been using the right keywords

Comment: @user1048442 Glad to know it helped. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if you feel it solves your question.